# Combining/merging Arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I'm trying to have an array of data to be passed to my html page templates to fill in missing data on the page. Here is the Array I have and the problem that is occuring.

```
protected $data = [
    "head" => [
            "css" => ["main"], /*add other default css files here*/
            "meta" => ["description" => HTML_DESCRIPTION, "keywords" => HTML_KEYWORDS, "charset" => HTML_CHARSET], // add other meta data here
            "JS" => [/*"src"*/], //set default js scripts here
            "title" => [0 => HTML_TITLE]
        ],
    "body" => [
        "title" => [
            "text" => BODY_TITLE_TEXT
        ],
        "navigation" => [
            "links" => [
                "Home" => "home",
                "Blog" => "blog"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Here is the Code I was using to try to get it to work.

```
    // $title = ["text" => "NEW TITLE"]

    public function build($title = [], $navigation = []){
    $defualts = $this->data;
    $data_to_add["body"] = ["title" => $title, "navigation" => $navigation];
    $data = array_merge_recursive($defualts,$data_to_add);
    require_once APP."/view/templates/body.php";
}
```

And the results I got from it

```
array(2) {
  ["head"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["css"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "main"
    }
    ["meta"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["description"]=>
      string(15) "DESCRIPTION"
      ["keywords"]=>
      string(41) "KEY1,KEY2,KEY3"
      ["charset"]=>
      string(5) "UTF-8"
    }
    ["JS"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["title"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "SITE TITLE"
    }
  }
  ["body"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["text"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(15) "OLD TITLE"
        [1]=>
        string(9) "NEW TITLE"
      }
    }
    ["navigation"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["links"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Home"]=>
        string(4) "home"
        ["Blog"]=>
        string(4) "blog"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see instead of replacing $data[body][title][text] to NEW TITLE, changes text from being a string to an array holding two values. I understand that array_merge_recursive is the reason for this. I'm just having troubles trying to write the code to create an array when the value is already an array and to replace the value if it's not.

for example, if I had a template page with a special navigation I may want to add $data["navigation]["links"]["sublinks"]["sublink1","sublink2","sublink3"]. with array_merge_recursive() I cannot add a sublinks array and replace "OLD TITLE" with "NEW TITLE" at the same time.

Thanks for any help the community can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and set the values directly instead of using `array_merge_recursive`:

```
$data = $this->data;
$data['body']['title'] = $title;
$data['body']['navigation'] = $navigation;
```

Comment: One problem I see though is I would have to restate the defaults instead of just adding to them. 
edit: if $navigation = ["sublinks"]["link1","link2"]; then $data["body"]["navigation"] would no longer include the "links" section.